Unbiased Cumulant Estimate - Fifth Cumulant
I am searching the definition of the $5^{th}$ unbiased cumulant estimate.
Let $K_j$, be the $j$-th unbiased cumulant estimate of a probability distribution, based on the sample moments.
Let $m_j$ be the sample moments for samples of a fixed size $n$, i.e. $m_j=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^j$, where $\bar{x}$ is the mean.
In Cramer's book (Mathematical Methods of Statistics), we read that we can compute the second, third and fourth unbiased cumulant estimates by using these equations:
$K_2 = \frac{n}{n-1}m_2$
$K_3 = \frac{n^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}m_3$
$K_4 = \frac{n^2}{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}((n+1)m_4 -3(n-1)m_2^2)$
My question for you is: do you know (or can you find) the definition of the $5^{th}$ unbiased cumulant estimate, based on the sample moments?
Of course this definition should be coherent with the aforementioned definitions of $K_2, K_3, K_4$ written by Cramer.
P.S. I noticed that there is a function named KStatisticToSampleCentral implemented in the package mathStatica of Wolfram Mathematica. This function is capable of finding this relation for each j-th unbiased cumulant estimate. However, I am not able to use this package:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Statistic.html
